# SQL Server 2012 - Week Date Sat To Friday

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff, dateadd

I think I'm really close to getting this but I'm just off the mark!

I'm trying to create a date (to report by) that will allow me select every week Saturday to Friday. 
Taking last week as an example the below code gives me the 29/07/2016 for a date range of 24/07/2016 to 30/07/2016 however I would like the date range to be 23/07/2016 to 29/07/2016 is this possible?

```
    DATEADD(WEEK,DATEDIFF(WEEK,0,[DateCreated]),4) AS [WeekCreated]
```

Many thanks in advance!

```
Id  Date    Week Commencing Week Ending
1   16/07/2016  16/07/2016  22/07/2016
2   17/07/2016  16/07/2016  22/07/2016
3   18/07/2016  16/07/2016  22/07/2016
4   19/07/2016  16/07/2016  22/07/2016
5   20/07/2016  16/07/2016  22/07/2016
6   21/07/2016  16/07/2016  22/07/2016
7   22/07/2016  16/07/2016  22/07/2016
8   23/07/2016  23/07/2016  29/07/2016
9   24/07/2016  23/07/2016  29/07/2016
10  25/07/2016  23/07/2016  29/07/2016
11  26/07/2016  23/07/2016  29/07/2016
12  27/07/2016  23/07/2016  29/07/2016
13  28/07/2016  23/07/2016  29/07/2016
14  29/07/2016  23/07/2016  29/07/2016
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`SET DATEFIRST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms181598.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you what you are looking for:

```
DATEADD(DAY, 6 - DATEPART(weekday,[DateCreated]), [DateCreated])
```

It will give you the following Friday for any given date. Keep in mind the `weekday` datepart is locale sensitive, so the offset may need to be adjusted depending on locale. Or you may need to do something more comprehensive to make it locale insensitive. `SELECT @@DATEFIRST` will give you the first day of the week in your locale. 7 is Sunday. You could incorporate that in if necessary.

Comment: Hi - thank you for your swift reply - I could not quite re create what I was after using these solutions (I got working week date ranges Eg 25th 31st) so above I have created a mini dataset to illustrate. I have shown both week commencing and week ending but it does not matter which one is created (If one is easier than the other) - I hope this helps :)

Comment: Ahhh I worked it out! As you say I need to reset my locale so Fri was first day of working week and the offset to - 7 so it picked up week ending (Each Friday) - Thank you all for your help :) Its always the same I had written all of the complicated bits of the code it was just this final hurdle I needed to get over!

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SET DATEFIRST 6 -- set Saturday as Week start day
SELECT DATEPART(DW,  CAST('23-jul-2016' as DATETIME))
```

check this- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms181598.aspx

Answer (score 0):

- Start of Range : `DATEADD(DAY, 6 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DateCreated]),
  [DateCreated])`
- End of Range : `DATEADD(DAY, -1 * DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DateCreated]),
  [DateCreated])`

Happy Coding